# How to run tsc --init in a subdirectory without installing it globally

Tags: yarnpkg, tsc

I have the following directory structure:

```
.
|-- package.json
|-- tsconfig.json
|-- src/
    |--subproject
```

I want to run `tsc --init` in `src/subproject`, but I don't want to install `tsc` globally. Running `yarn --cwd src/subproject tsc --init` doesn't work; it seems to be equivalent to `cd src/subproject; yarn tsc --init` which will still run `tsc` in the root directory.

Is it even possible to run `tsc` in this way?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work: `cd src/subproject; npx tsc --init`. But it doesn't seem like a good idea to imbed one project within an other.